# Install Spark 3.* on HDP with Ambari

Tags: apache-spark, ambari

We need to install Spark 3.* on HDP 3.1.5 but i can't to find some instructions.
I find this instruction
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Steps-to-install-supplementary-Spark-on-HDP-cluster/ta-p/244199
Does this work for spark 3?
How to add this service to ambari?
I'm need help

Comment: HDP isn't supported anymore, and Ambari does not (easily) allow for random software to be managed by it. I'd recommend using something else like Ansible/Puppet to install Linux packages across your cluster

Comment: @OneCricketeer i know about unsupported HDP. 
I saw with my own eyes that in some HDP-based clusters Spark3 is installed and it is displayed in Ambari

Comment: Ambari uses a [concept called "Stacks" for software it manages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/How-To+Define+Stacks+and+Services). You will need to build your own, or find one that supports Spark3. Personally, I am not aware of any.